# How to disable registration email in joomla 2.5 and 3

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

When registering a new Joomla user, an email is sent to the new users email address containing the username and password. Does anyone know how to disable this functionality, so that new users does not recieve this email?

Comment: I think you need to modify the com_users source, which is not recommended.

Comment: @FlavioEscobar No you don't have to modify the source for this. However I wanted to modify it because i had trouble finding this setting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Note

Important to note that there are two scenarios to consider, each with different answers.

Scenario 1) An unregistered user registers a new user account for `me@foo.com` by using the frontend, where `me@foo.com` represents the user's own email address.

Scenario 2) An admin registers a new user account for `her@foo.com` using the backend, where `her@foo.com` represents someone else's email address (i.e. the email address of the account you are trying to create).

Based on comments from the OP, this question is targeting situation 2 - i.e. in this situation we do NOT want Joomla! sending emails to `her@foo.com` after creating an account for her in the backend.

### Solution to Scenario 2

Login to the admin backend and then go to `Extensions` -> `Plugin Manager`.

From the Plugin Manager, locate the the plugin called `User - Joomla!` (Plugin type is `user` and Element aka Plugin file is `joomla`). Click on the title of the plugin to go into the configuration for this plugin.

Set `Notification Mail to User` to `No`.

Click `Save`.

### References

`plugins/user/joomla/joomla.xml`

`administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_user_joomla.ini`

### Rant

Finding this setting feels like discovering an easter egg. After you do find it you will see the seemingly straightforward description of the configuration setting, which, after rolling your mouse over the text at a moderate but not-too-fast velocity, triggers a popup balloon to begin a mocking fade in sequence, which, after finished, explains to you in a condescending tone exactly what the setting does. But before you've found this, you've most likely already visited the global configuration and played around with the email disable function there (but why would you want to globally disable emailing??), and you've probably also visited the User Module configuration, which also has a suspiciously named email configuration setting which however NOT apply to this situation (e.g. see http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/users/prevent-new-user-email-notification). You might have also searched around on the Internet and found some forum posts which suggest to disable this by hacking the Joomla! core (e.g. http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=280282). Seriously, with the recent discovery of the location of this configuration parameter I have to wonder what kind of altered state of mind the Joomla! folks had to have been in in order to come up with some of the weird ways in which things are organized in this strangely convoluted piece of software.

Comment: Thanks, Brandin, for the solution to this well convoluted secret :)

Comment: Thank you for this solution!, indeed hiden but this solves it

Answer (score 3):

Check this,

In `Joomla 3.x`  and `Joomla 2.5` there is option for avoid sending username/password to the new registered users.

You can check this,

```
Login to admin -> Users Menu - > Options from tool bar -> Send Password (Yes/No).
```

Customizing core file do not recommended.

Hope its helps..

Comment: #%&#% buggy joomla. It still sends out the email even tough the option is checked. I scanned the code, and it looks like this option is only read in the frontend, so probably works there. In the backend the 'sendpassword' - option is never read. So in my installation the password is still sent when users are added from the backend.